# MDC Logging With MuleSoft Runtime 4.4

Tags: logging, mule, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

I have problem with MDC in Anypoint Studio. I use new module in Runtime 4.4 to set variable in logger but it dosen't work. In the console I have output like this. But in the documentation I found that logger should also shows me this set variable like this:

INFO  2021-04-08 16:58:26,882 [[MuleRuntime].uber.15: [test-project-app].exmapleFlow.CPU_LITE @18f679] **[{correlationId=c85e16c0-98a4-11eb-bc34-cac765a2219b, processorPath=exmapleFlow/processors/2, testVar=testValue}]** org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Example

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUQyB.png)

Comment: Please use text instead of images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason.
Also kindly edit your question to include the set variable and logger in XML as text, no screenshots, to see what it is doing and the log4j2.xml. Kindly read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how to improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit the log4j2.xml. The default says this:

```
[processor: %X{processorPath}; event: %X{correlationId}]
```

But you need something like this:

```
[%MDC]
```

It's actually in the docs: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.4/logging-mdc#example-log4j2-xml-file-configurations

Comment: Yes, I change this but still dosen't work. I have like this:
<PatternLayout pattern="%-5p %d [%t] [%MDC] %c: %m%n"/>

Answer (score 0):

You have to change log4j2.xml appender a bit along with  %MDC.

Find the below working example link, I am sure it will work if you follow below link .

https://help.mulesoft.com/s/question/0D52T00005aW7E2SAK/mdc-logging-in-mulesoft-runtime-44

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem even when I updated the `PatternLayout` to have `MDC`.

Turns out, the default `log4j` ONLY contains the following:

```
<AppenderRef ref="file"/>
```

So, the logging variable I'm looking for is only showing up in my `app-name.log`.

I added a `Console` entry in my `Appenders` as follows:

```
<Appenders>

    <!-- Start of new -->
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%-5p %d [%t] [%MDC] %c: %m%n"/>
    </Console>
    <!-- End of new -->

    <RollingFile name="file" fileName="${sys:mule.home}${sys:file.separator}logs${sys:file.separator}app-name.log"
             filePattern="${sys:mule.home}${sys:file.separator}logs${sys:file.separator}tracing-module-%i.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%-5p %d [%t] [%MDC] %c: %m%n"/>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>
```

And added the following under `Loggers`:

```
<!-- Start of new -->
<AppenderRef ref="Console"/> 
<!-- End of new -->

<AppenderRef ref="file"/>
```

Changes will now show up in your `Studio Console` AND in your `app-name.log`.